# Add GridView in listView in android like Dropbox View

Tags: android, gridview, android-listview, android-custom-view

How can I add Grid View to the ListView.I could able to Implement but the problem is Grid View is not Visible its full height. I want to implement just like the Dropbox Photo CustomView which I have attached below. Please guide me in correct Path.

[image]

Thanks,
Chaitanya

Comment: So did you find a way to implement this?

Comment: I haven't try.. But I think we can achieve through Commonsware MergeAdapter.

Comment: @Chaitu have you already solve this problem?

Comment: I have solved the issue using https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders library. By using this library we can place headers as shown in the screen shot. Its just like GridView where the views are reusable.

Answer (score 1):

Using  github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders library for placing headers in gridview and refer this article http://www.programering.com/a/MjN0ITMwATU.html where is the demo as what are u expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are not supposed to add a scrollable view into another scrollable view. Both ListView and GridView are scrollable, so that just leads to trouble. I suspect that the Dropbox app does not use a GridView, but multiple LinearLayouts, that's at least what I would do. You just can not use an adapter in that case, but need to add the layouts and elements programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for update. I can use Linear Layouts to display Images but the thing is linear layouts are not optimizable (reusable) due to this the cache memory will increase and then app will get crash.